# How to check if certain numbers appear in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I'm relatively new to java. I'm trying to find if numbers from 0 - 4 are stored 
somewhere in an array of size 5. The array is populated by the user entering integers between 0-4. I have successfully managed to get it to confirm that the first number entered by the user is in the array however, the numbers after that not appearing.
So for example: If the user enters the numbers 2,2,2,1,3 I will get only 2 appears in the array as a result.

```
public static void checkEachNumber(int[] array)
{
    int currentNum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            currentNum = i;
            if(currentNum == array[j])
            {
                System.out.println(currentNum + " appears in the array");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(currentNum + " doesn't appear in the array");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve your problem you should simply remove the  have used in the else part of the array. 
Consider a case like this

ex.  2 1 4 3

when checking for i=1 it will first compare the value with 2 so it will come out of the loop.

```
public static void checkEachNumber(int[] array)
{
    int currentNum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        int flag=0;
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            currentNum = i;
            if(currentNum == array[j])
            {
                System.out.println(currentNum + " appears in the array");
                flag=1;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
              System.out.println("currentNum+"Doesn't appear in array");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a `break` statement, the loop stops running completely. In general, the way to scan for a match is going to look like this:

```
found_match = no

for (... in ...) {
    if (match) {
        found_match = yes
        break
    } 
}

if (found_match) {
    do_found_match_stuff();
}
```

Comment: Oh right okay. I did suspect the problem was with the break statements.